# Making an SNMP query for a router

Tags: networking, snmp, net-snmp, pysnmp

Is there a way to make SNMP queries to routers in the network to find out the devices connected to the network (using SNMP libraries like pySNMP)? 
Please do mention if there is anyother way of knowing devices connected to the network using a program.. I'm a noob in this. Please don't mind the immaturity of the question. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

If broadcast traffic reaches your routers and they respond to SNMP v1/v2c requests, you could try sending [broadcast SNMP queries](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/v1arch/asyncore/manager/cmdgen/transport-tweaks.html#broadcast-snmp-message-ipv4) for their device ID or some other metrics.